InvalidOperationException: Header value contains invalid characters
I am trying to integrate bKash Payment Gateway (PGW) in Unity using their rest APIs. The first step is generating token. For which it requires an Username & Password passed in their checkout/token/grant API's request header. The issue comes from the password. Because it contains special characters the API fails with an error. There is no option to change the password or passing the password anywhere else other then request header. Is there any solution for this?
It works perfectly fine in postman. My code also works fine if the password does not contains ")"
My code:
private IEnumerator CallApi(string api, string json, Action<string> onResponse) {
        var request = new UnityWebRequest(api, "POST");
        byte[] jsonToSend = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(json);
        request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(jsonToSend);
        request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.SetRequestHeader("username", _bkashData.username ?? "");
        request.SetRequestHeader("password", _bkashData.password ?? "");
        request.SetRequestHeader("X-App-Key", _bkashData.appkey ?? "");
        request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", _token ?? "");
        AppUtils.PrintLog($"bKash Api Request: {api} | Request: {json} | pass: {_bkashData.password}", AppConstants.Color.Other3);
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        AppUtils.PrintLog($"bKash Api Response: {api} | Response: {request.downloadHandler.text}", AppConstants.Color.Other3);
        if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success) {
            onResponse(request.downloadHandler.text);
        } else {
            AppUtils.PrintLog($"bKash Api Failed: {request.error} | API: {api} | Request: {json}");
        }
    }

The integration guide provided by bKash:

The error I am receiving:
InvalidOperationException: Header value contains invalid characters
UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader (System.String name, System.String value) (at <46c9a6f2bcd549f2b7ce644973f43ea8>:0)
bKashHandler+<CallApi>d__15.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/Utils/bKashHandler.cs:71)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <e509afeff7384f24a8f0ac30527ff01c>:0)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
bKashHandler:GetToken(Action) (at Assets/Scripts/Utils/bKashHandler.cs:55)
bKashHandler:CreatePayment(PriceData) (at Assets/Scripts/Utils/bKashHandler.cs:112)
DepositFundScript:OnSubmit() (at Assets/Scripts/GUI/DepositFundScript.cs:328)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update() (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@2.0.0/Runtime/UGUI/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:530)

Test password to reproduce the issue:
")^[su0ZC27M"


Have you tried to URL-encode the value, before passing it to SetRequestHeader?

what do you see if you send it through postman?

@C3roe maybe not, how can I do that?

@BugFinder it works without any errors when sent using postman.

yes but capture the difference so send this through postman, to check what you're sending against what you thought you sent

@BugFinder I am sending the same data. Basically what I am sending through postman is copied from what I am sending from Unity. Also, the issue is not it works on Postman, the issue is the error "InvalidOperationException"

OK, but it implies what you're sending from unity is different, Im trying to help you find the difference.. So have unity use postman as a proxy so you can see exactly what it sends

Nope, that's not the case here. I have total 4 merchants accounts of bKash, 3 of them works in Unity and only one doesn't work because the API never called due to that error. So the issue is when passing special characters such as ")^[su0ZC27M" into header when making API calls using UnityWebRequest. You will also find the same error if you add a value that have special character with in header and try to make API call.

Does it work if the password contains a ) not in the first character?

@SiddharthMehra to URL-encode, replace the value ) with %29 (ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Reserved_characters)

@TylerH no matter where I put ), the error remains the same until I remove it.

Also, URL-encoding the password makes the error go away but the API fails because of incorrect password.

@SiddharthMehra I would recommend asking on the Unity forums to see if they could assist there, or if you have a paid subscription that includes support, file a support ticket. In the meantime, the obvious short term solution is looking like you just won't be able to use passwords with special characters like ).

To me the RFC7230 Section 3.2.6 isn't super clear about how to properly encode header values. It seems that quoted strings are possible / allowed and the only values that need to be backslash encoded are the double quote and backslash character itself.
Unity's API isn't quite clear what kind of encoding or processing it may apply to the value, so it's not clear if you have to take care of it yourself.
Try to double quote the value (and ensuring that " and \ are escaped as \" and \\) it may fix the issue.
To me Unity's WebRequest should handle this escaping itself, so it may be a shortcoming of the UnityWebRequest implementation.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

@MattSeymour I mentioned that wrapping the value in double quotes may solve the issue. I edited my answer to be a bit more clear about that. The main issue is that Unity itself is rejecting the value, we just don't know exactly why. The exception is raised in SetRequestHeader. When I find some time I may create a repo-case and hopefully can be more specific.

double quoting the password does not have any effect, the error remains the same unless I remove ) from password.
